# Can't clearTimeout of variable even though it is a global function? JQuery responsive slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JQuery slider but the slide select is not working because of the timeout not clearing.

It is a global function but it needs to be cleared when the function is run.

```
$('.selector').click(function(){

var $slideID = $(this).attr('id'); // what slide to go to 
var $currentSlideID = $('.slider li').attr('id'); //what slide is visible
var goTo = $slideID - $currentSlideID;

clearTimeout(timer); //clear timer
$('.slider ul').animate({'right' : goTo + '00%'},500);
});
```

Its too long to put all of it in this page so I have liked to it in JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/tuyega/7/edit?js,output#J:L28

Once the timeout is set the selector does not work, but it does before.

Answer (score 3):

The `var` in front of your setTimeout assignment creates a variable that only exists within the scope of the $(document).ready callback. Removing the var keyword will now assign the setTimeout return value to the global `timer` variable, which is exposed to slideNext() and slidePrev().

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense, unfortunately there still seems to be a problem but I cannot see it, did you test it and it work?

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting a global variable. Yes you defined one, you also defined one in the scope of the document ready. So drop the var.

```
var timer; //create global var  <--yep this is global

$(document).ready(function(){

  //set and start slider
  var timer = setTimeout(function(){slideNext();},5000);   <--And not global
```

And the other issue is your animation code is wrong

```
$('.slider ul').animate({'right' : goTo + '00%'},500);
```

should be

```
$('.slider ul').animate({'left' : -goTo + '00%'},500);
```